# Uniqueness of the extention of the measure using the Halmos theorem

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

> **Proposition.** Let $X$ be a set, $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ an algebra e $\nu$ a measure on $\mathcal{A}$. Let $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ be two measure on the $\sigma-$ algebra $\sigma_0(\mathcal{A})$ such that $$\mu_1|_\mathcal{A}=\mu_2|_\mathcal{A}=\nu.$$ Then $\mu_1=\mu_2$.

**Proof.**$(i)$ Since $\nu$ is a $\sigma-$ finite measure on $\mathcal{A}$, exists an incrasing sequence $\{E_k\}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ such that $$X=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k,\quad \nu(E_k)<\infty\quad\text{for all}\quad k\in\mathbb{N}.$$ We set $$\mathcal{E_k}:=\{F\cap E_k\;|\; F\in\sigma_0(\mathcal{A})\},\quad k\in\mathbb{N}.$$ We prove that

> $$\mu_1|_\mathcal{E_k}=\mu_2|_\mathcal{E_k}\quad\text{for all}\quad k\in\mathbb{N}\implies \mu_1=\mu_2\tag 1.$$

For each $F\in\sigma_0(\mathcal{A})$ results $F=\bigcup_k (F\cap E_k)$; since the sequence $\{F\cap E_k\}$ is increasing we have $$\mu_1(F)=\lim_k\mu_1(F\cap E_k)=\lim_k\mu_2(F\cap E_k)=\mu_2(F).$$

$(ii)$ For all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ results: $$\mu_1(F\cap E_k)\le \mu_1(E_k)=\nu(E_k)<\infty,\quad \mu_2(F\cap E_k)<\infty.$$

As seen in $(i)$ it is therefore not restrictive to suppose that $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are finite.

> **Question.** why is it not restrictive to assume that the measures $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ are finite?

In such cases we define: $$\mathcal{M}:=\{F\in\sigma_0(\mathcal{A})\;|\;\mu_1(F)=\mu_2(F)\}.$$ Observe that $\mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{M}$. It is easy to prove that $\mathcal{M}$ is a monotone class.

From the Halmos theorem, according to which the monotone class generated by $\mathcal{A}$ coincides with the sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ and from the definition of $\mathcal{M}$ it follows that $\mathcal{M}=\sigma_0(\mathcal{A})$.

**Edit**

So as not to assume that the measures are finite, I decided to proceed as follows:

Since $\nu$ is a $\sigma-$ finite measure on $\mathcal{A}$, exists an incrasing sequence $\{E_k\}\subseteq \mathcal{A}$ such that $$X=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k,\quad \nu(E_k)<\infty\quad\text{for all}\quad k\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Let's consider $$\mathcal{M}:=\{F\in\sigma_0(\mathcal{A})\;|\;\mu_1(F\cap E_k)=\mu_2(F\cap E_k)\;\text{for all}\;k\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

***Claim*** **$\mathcal{M}$ is a monotone class**

Let $\{F_j\}\subseteq\mathcal{M}$ be an increasing sequence then $$\mu_1\bigg(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty (F_j\cap E_k)\bigg)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\mu_1(F_j\cap E_k)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\mu_2(F_j\cap E_k)=\mu_2\bigg(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty (F_j\cap E_k)\bigg)$$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Let $\{F'_j\}\subseteq\mathcal{M}$a decreasing sequence then $$\mu_1\bigg(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty (F_j\cap E_k)\bigg)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\mu_1(F_j\cap E_k)=\lim_{j\to\infty}\mu_2(F_j\cap E_k)=\mu_2\bigg(\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty (F_j\cap E_k)\bigg)$$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Observe that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ the sequence $\{F'_j\cap E_k\}_j$ is decreasing and $\mu_1(F'_j\cap E_k)\le\mu_1(E_k)=\nu(E_k)<\infty$, in the same way $\mu_2(F_j\cap E_k)<\infty$. For $(1)$ we have that
$$\mathcal{M}=\{F\in\sigma_0(\mathcal{A})\;|\;\mu_1(F)=\mu_2(F)\}$$
and the result follows as before.

It's correct?

Thanks!

Comment: By his arguments, it suffices to show that if $E \in \mathcal{A}$ has finite measure, then $\mu_1(F) = \mu_2(F)$ for all $F \in \sigma(\mathcal{A}), F \subset E$. Now consider $\mathcal{A}$ "restricted" to $E$ and $\sigma(A)$ "restricted" to $E$. You just have to verify that the former generates the latter.

Comment: @Mason Thanks for your kind comment, but I still don't understand why it's not restrictive to assume that the measures are finite...

Comment: He means that if we prove the theorem when $\mu_1(X) = \mu_2(X) < \infty$, then we can deduce the theorem for when $\mathcal{A}$ is a countable union of sets $X_j$ with $X_j \in \mathcal{A}$, $\mu_1(X_j) = \mu_2(X_j) < \infty$. Basically what you want to do is make the $X_j$ disjoint, and then apply the finite case result to each $X_j$ and add them up.